# Using Git, find commit that is reachable from both branchA and branchB

Tags: git, branch, commit

I have two branches where I want to find the latest shared commits. Shared commits mean only those commits that are reachable from both branches, but unreachable from other commits reachable from both branches. How can I do this?

Comment: Hi and welcome ardlen. Are you looking for [git-merge-base](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base)? (You write "find shared commitS" in plural, but if a commit is shared, all his ancestry also is.)

Comment: @RomainValeri It seems this is exactly what I need. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the missing answer:

```
git merge-base branchA branchB
```

In case both `branchA` and `branchB` point to the same commit, the output will the that commit sha1, otherwise it will be sha1 of the closest common ancestor. Note that it's possible to give more than 2 branches at the same time, see `git help merge-base` for more details.